# How to correctly copy a file when building an image on Docker Hub?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I have a fairly simple [Dockerfile](https://github.com/ad-si/TaskLite/blob/dbb50b86b78d71725d58e6d6f39156215351989b/Dockerfile), which works locally. However, when I build it on Docker Hub I get the following error:

```
Starting build of index.docker.io/adius/tasklite:next...
Step 1/16 : from haskell:8.8.4 as builder
---> 3ae1aa658125
Step 2/16 : workdir tasklite
---> Running in 73fa9ffd738e
Removing intermediate container 73fa9ffd738e
---> cdacdf2fede2
Step 3/16 : copy docker-stack.yaml stack.yaml
COPY failed: 
stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder266377042/docker-stack.yaml: 
no such file or directory
```

The build configuration seems to be fine as well:

[image: Screenshot build configuration]

How can I fix this?